# openssl ca is looking for unique_subject for group null?

Tags: openssl, ca, csr

I am trying to sign a certificate with a command like this:

```
openssl ca -create_serial -config openssl.cnf -cert ca-cert.pem -keyfile ca-key.pem -in key.csr -out cert.pem
```

It gives me an error:

```
140735532487624:error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/conf/conf_lib.c:323:group=(null) name=unique_subject
```

I searched various places for this particular error, as well as for general advice on signing certificates, but could not find anything relevant.

The man page on `ca` modules says that `unique_subject` is optional (besides, it is complaining about group(null), not default ca ...). 
I tried adding `unique_subject = no` to `openssl.cnf` under my default ca section, as well as at the top level, but that does not seem to help ...

I also tried adding a section `[null]` with `unique_subject = no` in it. Also didn't help.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try add unique_subject = no  and in the index.txt.attr file too.